# Entire section to the bottom of the page

Tags: spacing, sectioning, article

I'm writing a thesis in tex, and it is my first time. Some of the pages, in the beginning, need to be formatted in such a way, that they are flushed to the bottom of the page. The problem is, that all those pages are also a `\section` themselves. I know about `\vfill` but because the section heading also needs to be flushed down, I can't use it, because if I put the `\vfill` before the `\section`, it does nothing (I think that is because sections mark the start of a new page?). Is there any way to achieve it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}  
\begin{document}
\section{Some Previous Section}
Some previous text
\newpage
%\vfill does nothing here
\section*{Some Section Title}
%nor does it do anything here
This text, as well as the title, needs to be at the bottom of the page, to the top.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example

Comment: ```\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Some Previous Section}
Some previous text
\newpage

%\vfill does nothing here
\section*{Some Section Title}
%nor does it do anything here
This text, as well as the title, needs to be at the bottom of the page, to the top.

\end{document}```

Comment: @VojtaT. Add a `\null` before `\vfill`.

Comment: Or use `\vspace*{\fill}`.